# Extension in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-extensions

I was reading open source project and I found extension for a specific view controller like :

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        doSomething() 
    }

}

extension FirstViewController {
    func doSomething() {
        print("something")
    }
}
```

So why should I put `doSomething()` in extension if I can put it in `FirstViewController`. ?

Comment: Using extensions is a good way to group similar functions and improve readability.

Comment: In this case there is no advantage but if you extend `UIViewController` instead you don't need to declare the same method in different view controllers

Comment: yes @LeoDabus I get it but I want to know why many people use extension for a specific view controller

Comment: Personal preference.

Comment: @zneak So there's no difference or something ?

Comment: The only difference is that `doSomething` can't be overridden in a subclass due to limitations of how extensions work.

Comment: There are (or at least were, not sure whether the article still holds in 4.2) differences, however not many people are aware of them, let alone deliberately use extensions for them.  See: https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2016/12/swift-method-dispatch/

Comment: "So why should I put `doSomething()` in extension if I can put it in FirstViewController?" For the code you showed, you probably shouldn't. Can we move on now?

Comment: okay @matt when should I put it ?

Answer (score 2):

It is coder preference. For extension in that one can help separate code in multiple files. So, it helps to refactor code to read and understand easier.